# How to visualize infinite loop for vue infinite update loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

We have a fairly complex/nested system with a lot of Vuex usage amongst nested Vue components.  I am frequently running into the warning, `[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.` These infinite loops are not so easy to find, and have been taking me a long time to debug.

I look at the Vue warning stack trace and look at the last function that was called in my code, but this doesn't make it at all obvious to me why or where the infinite loop exists. I assume in these hard-to-debug cases that some parent component wants to re-render as a result of my sub-component's change, so then the sub-component runs that same vuex function again, causing the parent component to re-render, etc., but I can never trace to confirm or see exactly which function causes what part of a parent component or itself to re-render.

I am wondering if there is some way to visualize or see the infinite loop vue is getting stuck in?  I have been trying to explore `__ob__` and the like, but there are so many `deps` and `subs` that I don't understand where the issue is or what really to look for in `deps` and `subs`. I'm still having trouble understanding what specifically the infinite loop is each time it occurs.  Is there a way to tell Vue to go in the infinite loop so I can see a stack trace or some other debugging approach I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the full error message on your browser? From my experiences, you may need to copy the data before you put the model on child component. Like for array, you may want to have:

```
 var arrayToChildComponent = arrayData.slice();
```